# Intellij TFS Commit Failed

Tags: intellij-14

When I try to commit changes to my files after associating work item,I see the process message "Uploading Files" and then it gives me connection reset error .It used to work fine before .I rebooted my machine,tried Invalidate Cache and Restart ,and also checked my VPN connection .Nothing works .Using 14.0.5 Version.I am just trying to commit one file .I am working on Grails project .[image]

Log Snippet from IDEA logs :

```
    2017-12-27 05:55:54,421 [ 329736]   WARN - n.webservice.TfsRequestManager - 
    Read timed out 
org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.exceptions.ConnectionTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.exceptions.TfsExceptionManager.createTfsExceptionFromThrowable(TfsExceptionManager.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.exceptions.TfsExceptionManager.processException(TfsExceptionManager.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager.executeRequestInBackground(TfsRequestManager.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager.executeRequest(TfsRequestManager.java:267)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager.executeRequest(TfsRequestManager.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.tfs.VersionControlServer.uploadItem(VersionControlServer.java:1078)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.TFSCheckinEnvironment$3.executeRequest(TFSCheckinEnvironment.java:208)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.tfs.WorkstationHelper.processByWorkspaces(WorkstationHelper.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.TFSCheckinEnvironment.commit(TFSCheckinEnvironment.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.impl.VcsEventsListenerManagerImpl$Wrapper$1.invoke(VcsEventsListenerManagerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.commit(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$CommitProcessor.process(CommitHelper.java:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesUtil.processItemsByVcs(ChangesUtil.java:372)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangesUtil.processChangesByVcs(ChangesUtil.java:377)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$CommitProcessor.callSelf(CommitHelper.java:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper.e(CommitHelper.java:241)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper.access$500(CommitHelper.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$3$1.run(CommitHelper.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$3.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.a(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.a(ProgressManagerImpl.java:278)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ui.CommitHelper$3.run(CommitHelper.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.WebServiceHelper.httpPost(WebServiceHelper.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.tfs.VersionControlServer$28.execute(VersionControlServer.java:1097)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.core.tfs.VersionControlServer$28.execute(VersionControlServer.java:1078)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager$3.compute(TfsRequestManager.java:433)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.runWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:63)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager.executeRequestImpl(TfsRequestManager.java:421)
    at org.jetbrains.tfsIntegration.webservice.TfsRequestManager.executeRequestInBackground(TfsRequestManager.java:163)
```

Comment: It seems there is a time out issue. You could try the solution in this link to see whether it helps you: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206836695-Can-I-increase-time-out-value-

Comment: Tried that and still got the same error .Apparently it css and gsp files commit fine but not groovy and js files .I was able to commit before .This has happened after I opened the same project in new 2017 version I guess.Not sure what changed apart from iml files

Comment: Are you able to commit/check in the groovy and js files to TFS in Team Explorer?

Comment: Yes I was able to commit from tfs actually !!